# Java: Why am I able to have a reference to a non-null array of concrete parameterized types?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I was surprised, but ... this compiles:

```
public <T extends Database> ColMetaData<T>[] getTableColumnsAsEnums() {
            Class<? extends ColMetaData> cls = this.columnsEnumToken();
            return cls.<ColMetaData<T>[]>getEnumConstants(); }
```

Here is the method for columnsEnumToken:

```
// Returns a class token for an enum class
public Class<? extends ColMetaData> columnsEnumToken()  { 
    return this.e_colsToken; 
}
```

(I guess I can see why the second line below doesn't compile)

Some questions:

- Is this method "type safe"?
- Why does this line compile:

  `Class<? extends ColMetaData> cls = this.columnsEnumToken();`

  But this one fails to compile because of incompatible types:

  `Class<? extends ColMetaData<T>> cls = this.columnsEnumToken();`
- Why is it legal for method `getTableColumnsAsEnums()` to return an array of a concrete parameterized type, `ColMetaData<T>[]`.  I had thought that these were strictly verboten because there was no runtime way to have them operate type safely.

Comment: `cls.<ColMetaData<T>[]>getEnumConstants()` in of itself shouldn't compile because that's not a generic method.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer the first bullet point: what is `columnsEnumToken()`? What exactly is the incompatible types error message?

Comment: Yeah, it seems I can put any class I want into the angle brackets in the `return` statement and it will work.  It probably should report an error, but it seems the type information is simply ignored.

Comment: it's an odd rule in Java, you can add arbitrary type arguments, creating nonsense like `Math.<System>sin(1)`

Comment: @zhong.j.yu What? [This is madness](http://ideone.com/ci3nS6).

Comment: @PaulBellora I probed it a little and I though I found the rationale behind it. I forgot what it is though. It's just crazy.

Comment: An array of a type with generic parameters makes as much sense as a single variable - it's no more or less typesafe. It's true that the runtime type check that arrays do is *weaker* for a class with generic parameters, and it's possible to draw an analogy between this weakness and the rationale why `new T[]` is disallowed. I suppose the designers of the language just didn't care about preserving "exact" runtime type safety with arrays, as much as avoiding a case where *no* check (not even for the raw type) can be made at all.

Comment: @millimoose: more specifically for this question, it isn't just that new T[] isn't allowed, it is that new List<T>[] isn't allowed.  It's supposed to be illegal, and yet I have a non-null reference to a ColMetaDate<T>[] that compiles.

Comment: @scottb: just because you can't do `new List<T>[]` doesn't mean you can't have a `List<T>[]`

Comment: @newacct: Evidently.  However here is a passagae from Angelika Langer: "You can declare a reference variable of an array type whose component type is a concrete parameterized type. Arrays of such a type must not be created.  Hence, this reference variable cannot refer to an array of its type.  All that it can refer to is null...."  Apparently she would have been surprised by this code as well.

Comment: @scottb: Here: `List<T>[] foo = (List<T>[])new List<?>[5];` The value does not have to be `null`. You just have had to have an unchecked cast or raw type somewhere (either in your code or something you call, etc.). Is there any such warning in your code?

Answer (score 2):

**Class**

Theoretically, a Class cannot represent a parameterized type. For example, there is no class for `List<String>`, so you should not write `Class<List<String>>`, but only `Class<List>`.

However `Class<? extends List<String>>` could make sense. For example, if we have

```
    public class MyStringList extends ArrayList<String>{}
```

`MyStringList.class` is a `Class<MyStringList>` which is a `Class<? extends List<String>>`

**Generic Array**

There's nothing wrong with generic array type, it's just that Java forbids us to instantiate any... But the reason isn't very convincing. You can just go ahead and create one through casts, as long as you know it's safe.

Actually, there is a straightforward way in Java to create a generic array. When we call a method with varargs `X...`, an `X[]` object will be created - and X can be any type.

**Compatible assignment**

Apparently for some backward compatibility reason, we can assign a `List[]` to `List<String>[]`. That's why you can return a `ColMetaData[]` object while the return type is  `ColMetaData<T>[]`.

Comment: "For example, there is no class for List<String>": I believe I know what you're saying, but technically there is a class for List<String>: List<String>.class == List.class.

Comment: there is no `List<String>.class` :)

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what `ColMetaData<T>[]` represents. In Java, generics are strictly a compile time issue. At run time, they cease to exist. So what you're really telling the runtime is that you have an array of `ColMetaData` instances, which indeed is a concrete type. This is different, however, than using an arbitrary type for the array. The array type is still `ColMetaData`, and Java can determine this at compile time. Then the compiler needs only to track that the instances you store use the correct generic type.

Comment: No argument.  However, this is rather very different from the implicit guarantee that when you declare ColMetaData<Client_Table> instances that they will be distinct and separate from ColMetaData<Encounter_Table> instances.  That distinction, as you point out, ceases to exist in parameterized array types ... which causes all assurances of type safety to vanish.

Comment: You may be right; I would have to test that. "Type safety" is all at compile time. It all depends on how the compiler handles it. If the compiler does fail in this situation, I would consider that to be a bug. Truth be told, I suspect all type safety can be bypassed at the bytecode level. Mocks probably already do something in this regard.

Comment: No need to test.  Angelika Langer has some tests here in her Generics FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104